# npm install with error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1 | npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, node-sass

I try to install modules on `windows 11` using `npm 8.5.5`. When i enter `npm install` i get :

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\faris\\Downloads\\learnplus\\learnplus-v4.4.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\faris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\faris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                                ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\faris\\Downloads\\learnplus\\learnplus-v4.4.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\faris\Downloads\learnplus\learnplus-v4.4.0\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

It seems like `node-sass` install error. The environment is below:

> npm version: 8.5.5
>
> system : windows 11
>
> node version: 16.15.0

I'm trying to install the gym in npm with command `npm install gyp`, but there is still the same error. Then, i'm trying to install with the command `npm i gyp`, but there is still the same error.

Comment: The project depends on an old version of `node-sass` which depends on an old version of `node-gyp` which requires a working Python 2 interpreter to be installed.